# SQLite names columns differently than expected

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I'm running the following SQL Statement

```
SELECT [i].[ByteColumn], [r].[ReferenceDate] 
FROM [Reference] [r] INNER JOIN (
SELECT  [Import].[ImportID], [Import].[ByteColumn] 
FROM [Import]) AS i  
ON ([r].[ImportID] = [i].[ImportID])
ORDER BY [i].[ByteColumn] ASC
```

The data comes back as expected but the column names are i and r? I would expect them to be ByteColumn and ReferenceDate. In fact on all other databases I've tried this with this is exactly what they are called?

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a **alias name** to your columns which you are selecting and its done. Try this:

```
SELECT [i].[ByteColumn] as [ByteColumn], [r].[ReferenceDate] as [ReferenceDate]
FROM [Reference] [r] INNER JOIN (
SELECT  [Import].[ImportID], [Import].[ByteColumn] 
FROM [Import]) AS i  
ON ([r].[ImportID] = [i].[ImportID])
ORDER BY [i].[ByteColumn] ASC
```

From the doc:

> SQLite does not (currently) make any promises about column names on
>   queries that omit the AS clause. If you use an AS clause, then the
>   column name is guaranteed to be the label to the right of AS. If you
>   omit the AS clause, then the column names might change from one
>   release of SQLite to the next.